# Looking for Tools for writing ECRG

Tags: raster-conversion, ecrg

Does anyone know of consumer-level tools that can write Enhanced Compressed Raster Graphics (ECRG - MIL-PRF-32283) files, based on some other raster format (e.g. GeoTIFF, or some image plus world file). Open Source would be preferred, but I'm interested in identifying any potential sources to help test a reader.

There are several readers (GDAL, FalconView, ESRI and Intergraph products), but I'm specifically looking for writers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not aware of any commercial tools that can produce ECRG files. The [specification](http://geohack.net/gis/MIL-PRF-32283.pdf) looks to be well-specified, and it doesn't seem like an impossible format to create a writer for. The only producer of ECRG files I'm aware of is NGA and its affiliates, and I would hazard a guess that they don't rely on existing commercial tools for this task.

Note that the specification includes NITF 2.1 file frames ([relevant GDAL documentation](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_nitf.html)), XML table of contents, and Shapefiles for footprint information. You are in luck in the sense that GDAL supports writing all three of these formats natively, including the JPEG2000 compression required for ECRG. So, most of the work will be in conforming to the data specification. Provided that this is currently exclusively a military format, it's unlikely this format will be supported by the community without some leg-work.

Comment: This doesn't really tell me what I wanted to know, but I'll concede this as a reasonable response given the situation.

Answer (score 1):

GDAL can read ECRG, but not write, which means that most regular GIS software will only read and not write it. FME can't write it, and they are one of the few software products that write their own read/write libraries (and only when GDAL can't do it!).

I highly doubt you will find something to do it.

- http://www.safe.com/fme/format-search/
- http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html

Comment: I understand the GDAL limitation (per the question), and I know the FalconView implementation isn't based on GDAL. However if there are readers, then the product has to be coming from some tool....